# merging two columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider this data frame in R which contains two columns named a and b:

```
a     b
a1   b1  
a2   b2  
a3   b3
```

I want to produce a list by merging columns a and b in this way:

```
 a1  b1  a2  b2  a3  b3
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can transpose (`t`) the dataset and then concatenate (`c`) the `matrix` output to get a `vector`

```
 c(t(df1))
 #[1] "a1" "b1" "a2" "b2" "a3" "b3"
```

Or use `as.vector`.

```
 as.vector(t(df1))
 #[1] "a1" "b1" "a2" "b2" "a3" "b3"
```

Usually, for converting a 'data.frame' to 'vector', `unlist` is used, but it will unlist by column wise.  That is the reason for transposing the dataset and using `c` or `as.vector`.

Or to get `list` output, `as.list` can be used.

```
  as.list(t(df1))
```